# d3: Calculate midpoint of line between two nodes, draw line extending at 90 degree angle from it to a new node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3, assume there is node1 and node2, represented by circles that are next to each other horizontally.  There is a short horizontal line (a path, I guess) connecting node1 and node2.

How do I:
(1) find the midpoint of that line/path, and
(2) give that midpoint a new name or ID that I can work with programmatically, so that I can
(3) draw new vertical lines/paths from that midpoint to new node3, node4, and node5?

Comment: not familiar with d3 but you can find the midpoint of ANY line by adding the two endpoints and dividing by 2

Comment: It's always useful to provide some code to show what you've tried so far. And this is really a basic trigonometry problem, not specific to d3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the mid point of each lines and draw lines from that point to other nodes using the code below. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1uxenjwh/)

```
function drawLines(d){
    var x1 = nodes[d.source].x;
    var x2 = nodes[d.target].x;
    var y1 = nodes[d.source].y;
    var y2 = nodes[d.target].y;
    var otherNodes = nodes.filter(function(n,i){ return i!=d.source  || i!=d.target });
    otherNodes.forEach(function(otherNode){
         svg.append("line")
            .attr("x1",function(d){ return otherNode.x; })
            .attr("y1",function(d){ return otherNode.y; })
            .attr("x2",function(d){ return (x1+x2)/2; })
            .attr("y2",function(d){ return (y1+y2)/2; })
            .attr("class","line");
    });

}
linksEls.each(drawLines);
```